# What is the best way to implement a tree in matlab?

Tags: matlab, tree

I want to write an implementation of a (not a binary) tree and and run some algorithms on it. The reason for using the matlab is that the rest of all programs are in matlab and it would be usful for some analysis and plotting. From an initial search in matlab i found that there aren't thing like pointers in matlab. So I'd like to know the best ( in terms on convinience) possible way to do this in matlab ? or any other ways ?

Comment: If you can manage with a binary Red-Black tree implementation, it's stupid simple: [`import java.util.TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html#HashMapTreeMapClasses)

Comment: @MattB. you have some example about how use `java.util.TreeMap` in matlab like a tree ?

Comment: @MattB. [you can use TreeMap like a map](https://gist.github.com/juanpabloaj/5793514), but, how you can use like a tree ?

Comment: @JuanPablo - it's an *implementation* of a tree for a generic map.  It doesn't expose the tree's internals.  It simply guarantees O(log n) time cost for some operations.  ([Oracle has changed the documentation link; it's here now](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html))

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with MATLAB objects but you must make sure you use [handle objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brtm8si.html) and not value objects because your nodes will contain cross-references to other nodes (i.e. parent, next sibling, first child).

Comment: @petrichor Thanks. I fixed it. I guess it never worked since I pasted in a session ID originally. D'oh!

Answer (score 5):

This question is very old but still open. So I would just like to point readers to [this implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35623-tree-data-structure-as-a-matlab-class) in plain MATLAB made by yours truly. [Here](http://tinevez.github.io/matlab-tree/) is a tutorial that walks you through its use.

Answer (score 4):

`Matlab` is very well suited to handle any kind of graphs (not only trees) represented as [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) or [incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix).

Matrices (representing graphs) can be either dense or sparse, depending on the properties of your graphs.

Last but not least, graph theory and linear algebra are in very fundamental ways related to each other [see for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory), so `Matlab` will be able to provide for you a very nice platform to harness such relationships.

Comment: How can I use them...matlab only supports arrays and cell arrays, i cannot form linked lists in matlab. using matrices will be nightmare in terms of memory consumption, i don't have a clue.

Comment: @Rajesh D: Well, you can use sparse matrices (see more here http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html). Thanks